# JavaFX StackPane get Item in Front

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

as the title says, I'm using a StackPane where I stack my AnchorPanes(`AnchorPaneName.setFront()`). I want to know which AnchorPane is on top/in front. Is it possible to get the AnchorPane which is in Front?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The front one will be the last item in the parent's child list, i.e. call

```
getChildren().get(getChildren().size()-1)
```

on the parent (the `StackPane`, if I understand your question correctly).